# SQL Server - Existing Records on INSERT creating really high autonumber value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I understand that the behavior for autoincrementing ID fields changed in the newest versions of SQL Server. I also understand that the "sequential" behavior was never really a guarantee to begin with any way, but was nice that it usually exhibited a +1 type behavior. :)

I have an application that attempts to write several records quite frequently. The SQL I am running is below. I thought the NOT EXISTS and TRY/CATCH block, would prevent the "attempt" of an already-existing record, preventing the extremely high (and growing fast) autonumber ID field I'm using. Was trying to save myself from having to do a "SELECT" first, checking the result, and then doing an INSERT if empty (using PHP). I thought this SQL would do that for me all at once.

I guess my real concern is that at the rate my number field is growing, it's going to be a problem soon. :) After 1 day, it's already 90,000,000+ (it's an "int" type field).

Any suggestions on preventing this?

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT
   * 
FROM
   EventsTable 
WHERE
   EventType LIKE 'Alarm' 
   AND EventSource LIKE 'RackB, Circuit 4' 
   AND EventDescription LIKE 'Comm Timeout' 
   AND EventDateTime LIKE '08-05-2015 13:25:02' 
   AND EventLocation LIKE 'MT01')) BEGIN TRY INSERT 
INTO
   EventsTable
   ( EventDateTime, EventType, EventSource, EventDescription, EventSubSystemKey, EventViewKey, EventLocation, EventPriority ) 
VALUES
   ('08-05-2015 13:25:02','Alarm','RackB, Circuit 4','Comm Timeout','1','4','MT01','Notice') 
END TRY BEGIN CATCH 
END CATCH
```

Comment: You have 90,000,000+ events occurring in a single day? I am curious to find out what kind of events are you logging in?

Comment: No, not that many, but there are HUGE gaps in the autonumbers that are used because of the "duplicate" INSERTS. The ID's aren't sequential.

Comment: Yeah, I think like @Siyual pointed out below, there are a few issues with your not exists query that you need to handle before. First being the use of `Like` instead of `=` and the other one being the datetime comparison which is usually a bad idea since that datetime only would happen once.

Comment: I understand. On the datetime comparison, that is effectively why it's part of the key - it is what helps make the records unique. On the comparisons,  most of my fields are varchar, I just happen to not "need" any wildcards in the comparisons. LIKE should be fine on those. I think part of the problem (seeing it now) is I'm doing a LIKE for '08-05-2015' but in the db it's '2015-08-05'.

Comment: Why not use `getdate()-1  instead`? As far as I can tell, you are only interested in preventing any records that has already occurred in that timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the true answer to your problem, but this jumped out to me immediately:

```
 AND EventDateTime LIKE '08-05-2015 13:25:02'
```

This will always return `false` if your `EventDateTime` field is truly a `DATETIME` type.  Since this condition cannot ever be met, the `NOT EXISTS` will always report that the data is not present.  Thus, you will always be inserting data, whether it truly exists in the database or not.

You should change your `LIKE` statements to be `=`.  None of the `VARCHAR` comparisons are using wildcards, and from what it appears, it is breaking your `DATETIME` comparisons.

Edit:

If you need to use `LIKE` with a wildcard on this statement, you'll need to cast the `EventDateTime` column to a `VARCHAR` for this.  `LIKE` isn't designed to handle `DATETIME` datatype (as far as I'm aware), so you'll need to do something like this:

```
AND Convert(Varchar, EventDateTime, 121) LIKE '08-05-2015 13:25:02%'
```

Comment: Interesting.. that's field is actually part of my primary key. What's the "right" way to compare it?

Comment: Use `=` for comparisons.  `LIKE` should only be reserved for `VARCHAR` comparisons where you're using certain wildcards or patterns.

Comment: You know, I might just need to add a wildcard to the end of that datetime since it has a ".000" at the end of it in the db. Also just noticed the date part isn't quite the sql server format, so i'll check that as well.

Comment: Updated answer to include an alternate `LIKE` comparison since you don't know the trailing decimal values.

Comment: Ahh!! I'll try that. That's what I was looking for! Let me try that out and I'll report back. EDIT: to get that conversion to work, I had to change the date in the comparison manually to '2015-08-05' - I could probably do this on the PHP side before building the query, but that might be tedious...